# Get everything in string after @ and before whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I have got this string

```
$string="@smn and @someone are web developers"
```

and i want to get `@smn` and `@someone` from string.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` with regex `/(?<!\w)@\w+/`

```
$string="@smn and @someone are web developers";
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)@\w+/',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/o4p4U)**

Comment: When i try to echo it works.But when i try to insert it into database it says "Array to string conversion" and insert Array.Here is my query$query=$con->query("INSERT INTO notifications(Post_id,Username,Initiator,type,`Date`) VALUES('$IdU','$matches[0]','$Name','Mention',NOW()) ");

Comment: Use it as `$matches[0][0]` or `$matches[0][1]` it will return value